# Regex to match word not start and end with certain character (in sentence)

Tags: regex

I want to matched a word which doesnt start with << OR doesnt end with >> (in sentence).

Example sentence:

```
Lorem Ipsum It has survived not only five centuries. <<Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum>> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of.
```

In this sentence only 2 "Lorem Ipsum" matched our rule (doesnt start with << OR doesnt end with >>)

I tried this but doesnt work

```
/(?!<<)(lorem ipsum)(?!>>)/i
```

How to make it work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a negative lookahead `(?!<<)` both before and after the word. Additionally, you have not included the global flag 'g', so depending on your environment it may return after the first match. Try changing the first lookahead to a lookbehind, and optionally adding the 'g' flag:

`(?<!<<)(lorem ipsum)(?!>>)`

or as a JavaScript RegExp litteral:

`/(?<!<<)(lorem ipsum)(?!>>)/gi`

Try it out here: https://regex101.com/r/Pa1b5n/1